# how to pass parameters to URDF in ros2 launch file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know we can do this in ROS-1, but I'm not exactly sure with the syntax in ROS2.

Just a small try I had given:

```
start_robot_state_publisher_cmd = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    name='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 'frame_prefix': 'robot1/', 'robot_description': Command([robot_desc,'tfpre:=', 'robot1/'])}],
    arguments=[urdf])
```

tf pre is the parameter I'm trying to pass. But, I'm certainly sure there is some mistake with this ,method.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381646/how-to-pass-parameters-to-urdf-in-ros2-launch-file?/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way to do it is as follow

```
import xacro
...
urdf = xacro.process_file(file_path, mappings={'tfpre': 'robot1/'}).toxml()
# Use urdf
```

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2021-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0